# How do I Convert a Geometry Node input to Integer

Tags: node-editor, geometry

I'm trying to add an input to my nodes, I need it to be an integer (Lime Green) I know it can be done because one of the download examples has them set up like that, but I can't find in the documentation or anywhere online how to change their type

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the type until now. But you can use the subdivide node and connect level (which is an integer) to the group input. Then delete the subdivide node and connect whatever you want to your new input integer socket.